# Arbitrarily order array keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I need to reorder by some arbitrary definition, and I'm not sure how uksort could help.

Here's the array I want to sort:

```
[
    [Alice] => foo,
    [Bob] => foo,
    [John] => foo,
    [Steve] => foo
]
```

I want to reorder this array to be Bob, Alice, Steve, then John... or some other explicitly declared order. Is there a way to take a *separate* array and use *that* to reorder the keys of the original?

I know I could just loop over the array and build a new array, but that seems inelegant...

Answer (score 0):

ok after some more poking about this is sexier:

```
$finialOrderArray = array_merge(array_flip($orderArray), $array);
```

maybe there a sexier way, but a basic foreach loop though the sort order seems like a good approach

```
<?php
$array=array('Alice' => 'foo','Bob' => 'foo','John' => 'foo','Steve' => 'foo');
$orderArray=array('Bob', 'Alice', 'Steve', 'John');


function orderArray($array, $orderArray) {
    $ordered = array();
    foreach($orderArray as $k) {
        if(array_key_exists($k,$array)) {
            $ordered[$k] = $array[$k];

        }
    }
    return $ordered;

print_r(orderArray($array,$orderArray));
  //Array ( [Bob] => foo [Alice] => foo [Steve] => foo [John] => foo )
```